# Which data type to use for a very large numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, types, largenumber

I have to store the number `600851475143` in my program. I tried to store it in `long long int` variable and `long double` as well but on compiling it shows the error

```
integer constant is too large for "long" type.
```

I have also tried `unsigned long long int` too.  I am using MinGW 5.1.6 for running g++ on windows.

What datatype should I use to store the number?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`long long` is fine, but you have to use a suffix on the literal.

```
long long x = 600851475143ll; // can use LL instead if you prefer.
```

If you leave the `ll` off the end of the literal, then the compiler assumes that you want it to be an `int`, which in most cases is a 32-bit signed number. 32-bits aren't enough to store that large value, hence the warning. By adding the `ll`, you signify to the compiler that the literal should be interpreted as a `long long`, which is big enough to store the value.

The suffix is also useful for specifying which overload to call for a function. For example:

```
void foo(long long x) {}
void foo(int x) {}

int main()
{
    foo(0); // calls foo(int x)
    foo(0LL); // calls foo(long long x)
}
```

Comment: well thanks but can anyone explain me why do we do this? what happens by adding the literals??

Comment: You really should use upper-case LL here.

Comment: I did add that as a comment, but honestly I don't think I've ever confused an l with a 1 in Courier New, which is what most editors use as their font.

Comment: The reason we have to add the Ls, in short, is because the C++ compiler is just too stupid. It won't try it as an int, then as a long, then as a long long, etc. So we have to tell it that it's a long long in order for it to allocate enough space for it on the heap (because literals get their own space, too, before they're assigned to your variable). My general rule for C++: Tell it everything. It's not very good at deduction. If you want a Sherlock Holmes, ask Python. :D

Answer (score 10):

You had the right idea with `long long int` (or `unsigned long long int`), but to prevent the warning, you need to tell the compiler that the constant is a `long long int`:

```
long long int value = 600851475143LL;
```

Those "L"s can be lower-case, but I'd advise against it -- depending on the font, a lower-case "L" often looks a lot like a one digit ("1") instead.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the GNU MP Bignum library http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Way to shoot a mouse with an Elephant gun.

Comment: Well, due to how the title of the question was written, I think a lot of people hunting elephants end up here.